# "Not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#, methods

I'm working with arrays and methods. I'm working on writing a code that will calculate the average of numbers entered by user in an array. I came up with the first method but VS tells me that "not all code paths return a value". When I tested the code in the Main() method it works well but when it's inside my GetValues() method i get the error.

I read all other posts but they not quite make sense to me because of their specificity. I know this isn't too difficult but I'm a beginner and trying to understand this myself.

My program isn't done yet, the following code is just the first part (method) of my program. Once GetValues () work, the idea is then to call this method from another method that will calculate the average. Again, GetValues() is supposed to capture the array.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace testscores
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }

        private static int[] GetValues()
        {

            string inValue;
            int[] score = new int[5];
            int total = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Score {0}: ", i + 1);
                inValue = Console.ReadLine();
                score[i] = Convert.ToInt32(inValue);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
            {
                total += score[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to return the integer array `score`?

```
   ....
        for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
        {
            total += score[i];
        }
        return score;
    }
```

So you can capture this array when you call it like so

```
int[] scores = GetValues();
```

Comment: Thanks man, that's exactly what I did. Now, if I want to call that returned value from another method. Should I add a parameter to the method header? such as: private static int [] GetValues (int score)

Comment: @Oskar No, that would mean that you meant to pass an int into your method that you could access by the name score...you don't need to pass anything in, and you're creating a local array named score

Comment: @kekekela Thanks!  So if I want to call the value stored in GetValues() from another method, should I just call it typing "GetValues" from that method?  Hope I'm explaining myself

Comment: @Oskar yeah, the code snippet in the bottom of shredder's answer is how you would do it, your returned value is held in the scores variable on the left side of the equals

Answer (score 2):

Your function is declared to return `int[]` but there is no single `return` statement within it.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of your function GetValues() you need to return an int[].  Which is what the compiler error is telling you; if you follow all code paths in GetValues(), there is at least ONE that does not return a value.  (add `return score` to the end of the function).

Comment: Thanks Suroot !  I knew it had to be something easy. I don't get that error anymore. Now, does this mean i have to write a parameter "int score" at the method header?  i.e. private static int [] GetValues (int score)

Answer (score 1):

Your method is not returning anything and is not declared void, but int[]

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error is because you need to add a `return score`

Beyond that, you're also doing a loop to populate the local variable 'total', and then doing nothing with that which seems like a design/logic error.  Basically that code can just be removed unless you make total a member of the class or out param instead of local variable.  You could also just be doing this in the first loop.

Comment: I believe you meant `return score;`.

Comment: return score[i]; would return an int, not an `int[]`

Comment: also the `+ 1` there has nothing to do with accessing the array

Comment: @shredder yeah, edited that out I guess while you were typing your comment

Comment: @Shredder, I believe the +1 is there so the user won't see that he has to enter a value 0. Instead, this will add 1 to that initial value so it will display as "Enter Score 1".   Am I right?