# not all code paths return a value using html agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am rather new to c# and the html agility pack I have wrote this code to parse apart of a webpage.

```
private IList<Category> GetFeatureSubCategories(HtmlNode std, Category category)
    {
        List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
        {
            if (category.name == "Featured")
            {
                var nodes = std.SelectNodes("//span[contains(@class,'widget')] [position() <= 4]");

                foreach (var node in nodes)
                {
                    string name = SiteParserUtilities.ParserUtilities.CleanText(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(node.InnerText));
                    string url = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
                    string identifier = url.Split('/').Last().Replace(".html", "");
                    WriteQueue.write(string.Format(" Category [{0}].. {1} ", name, url));

                    IList<Category> sub = GetSubCategories(std);
                    Category c = new Category()
                    {
                        active = true,
                        Categories = sub.ToArray(),
                        description = "",
                        identifier = identifier,
                        name = name,
                        Products = new Product[0],
                        url = url,
                    };
                    StatisticCounters.CategoriesCounter();
                    categories.Add(c);
                }


            }

        }

    }
```

I am receiving an error message saying "SiteParser.GetFeatureSubCategories(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode, Category)': not all code paths return a value" I was just wondering whether anyone would be able to give me some advice in why this error message is occurring. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: you are not returning categories any where in the code

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Not all code paths return a value"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936615/not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

Your method is suppose to return an object of type `IList<Category>`, you don't have `return` statement anywhere in your code. Probably you want to return `categories` from your method, you can place the return statement just before the method end.

```
private IList<Category> GetFeatureSubCategories(HtmlNode std, Category category)
{
        List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
        {
        //.................
return categories;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explanatory: your code does not `return` anything, while the method's signature promises it does.

`return categories;` at the end of the method will do.

Answer (score 1):

The method's promises to return a `IList<Category>` here:

```
private IList<Category> GetFeatureSubCategories
```

So it has to return it in any way(or at least `null` which is the default value).

But you don't return a list. So just add `return categories;` at the end.

```
private IList<Foo> GetFeatureSubCategories(HtmlNode std, Foo category)
{
    List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
    {
        if (category.Name == "Featured")
        {
            var nodes = std.SelectNodes("//span[contains(@class,'widget')] [position() <= 4]");
            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
               // blah ...
            }
            // blah ...
        }
    }
    return categories;
}
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Methods with a non-void return type are required to use the return
>   keyword to return a value.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from a method which declare to return ILIst

add `return categories;` at after second last '}' bracket

Answer (score 0):

Your method retuns a `IList<Category>` but you aren't returning an `IList<Category>` anywhere in your code. Call: -

```
return categories;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not returing categories any where in the code

Add return statement at the end of your code like i hv added

```
private IList<Category> GetFeatureSubCategories(HtmlNode std, Category category)
{
    List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
    {
        if (category.name == "Featured")
        {
            var nodes = std.SelectNodes("//span[contains(@class,'widget')] [position() <= 4]");

            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                string name = SiteParserUtilities.ParserUtilities.CleanText(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(node.InnerText));
                string url = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
                string identifier = url.Split('/').Last().Replace(".html", "");
                WriteQueue.write(string.Format(" Category [{0}].. {1} ", name, url));

                IList<Category> sub = GetSubCategories(std);
                Category c = new Category()
                {
                    active = true,
                    Categories = sub.ToArray(),
                    description = "",
                    identifier = identifier,
                    name = name,
                    Products = new Product[0],
                    url = url,
                };
                StatisticCounters.CategoriesCounter();
                categories.Add(c);
            }
        }
    }
         return categories;
}
```