# "Not all code paths return a value" error message

Tags: c#

I wrote this method but it is giving me this error message.
"**Not all code paths return a value**" on **GetInputstring**
What do I have to do? Thanks in advance.

```
    public string GetInputstring(string myInput)
    {
        int myInt;

        Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
        myInput = Console.ReadLine();

        myInt = Int32.Parse(myInput);

        if (myInt <= 0)
        {
            Write1(myInt);
        }
        else
        {
            Write2(myInt);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: either make it public void or return a string.

Comment: you need to return the string or you need to make your method void. Also consider using Int32.TryParse

Comment: What part of the error message didn't you understand? Not all code paths return a value. Fix it by making sure every code path returns a value. (Someday somebody will explain to me why people don't read compiler error messages.)

Comment: Thanks all for your response. What does Void do?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Not all code paths return a value"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936615/not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

Comment: I figure you are learning.  That is cool.  Trying to learn the basics via Q&A is going to take forever and is going to frustrate a lot of people.  I strongly suggest reading at least an entry to .NET article or book.  As Raymond Chen commented, the error message is clear.  Your follow up question regarding what does Void [sic] do? is equally without regard for the fact that this is answered within the set of expected reading.  These are basic elements of the languages which StackOverflow is not the right place to learn them.

Answer (score 3):

You have to return `string` from the method but you are not returning the string that is reason for getting the error. You can return the input being taking from user and stored in `myInput` by using `return` statement.

```
public string GetInputstring(string myInput)
{
    int myInt;

    Console.Write("Please enter a number: ");
    myInput = Console.ReadLine();

    myInt = Int32.Parse(myInput)

    if (myInt <= 0)
    {
        Write1(myInt);
    }
    else
    {
        Write2(myInt);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
    return myInput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method does not return anything.  If you are not going to return a value it should be set to void instead of `public string GetInputString(string myInput)` such as in the format `public void GetInputString(string myInput)`.  If you do actually want your method to return a value you must return something from each possible branch/path of your code.

In case you need some additional tips here is the MSDN documentation for the `return` reserved word: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx